# Postgres use a calculated string as a field name to filter by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `schedule` table created as such

```
CREATE TABLE schedule (
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    title varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    monday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    tuesday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    wednesday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    thursday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    friday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    saturday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    sunday bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
);
```

now I have want to run a query and filter schedules down to the ones the current day of week is true, but not sure how to.

What I've tried is query below gets me the day of week.

```
select ('{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday}'::text[])[date_part('dow', current_date) + 1]
```

but yet I can't do

```
select * from schedule 
where ('{sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday}'::text[])[date_part('dow', current_date) + 1] = true
```

how would you filter the schedules by the ones which the current date of week is true?

Comment: What do you want to do there? Please show sample data, the expected result and explain the logic behind. As the question currently stands, I think this table doesn't make sense. There is no need to use seven boolean columns for each weekday. The weekday can simply be fetched from the date you're working on, it's not required to save it anywhere.

Comment: @JonasMetzler there's a schedule that only applies to certain days of week, say only on Monday, Tuesday. I want to filter the schedules down to the ones enabled for today. What's ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use texts at all, simply build an array containing the booleans of your 7 weekday columns and set your `where` condition to use exactly that.

```sql
select * from schedule 
where (ARRAY[sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday])[date_part('dow', current_date) + 1]
```